# Picasso not loading JPG format

Tags: android, picasso

I'm getting some images from api and showing them via picasso library. Unfortunately it isn't showing .JPG formatted images while it perfectly works with jpg images. Is there anyone who had such problem? Is there any cure or we can't use picasso with JPG?

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Share your link that's not load in picasso.

Comment: Whats the difference between JPG and jpg?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, I had the same problem in general with android studio, so this doesn't regard strictly Picasso library. What I know is that in a case (.jpg) those files are recognized as multimedia files (so treated that way) in the opposite case (.JPG) they are considered as files and treated more generally.

Usually I convert all .PNG into .png and all .JPG into .jpg.

Hope it can help you!

Comment: give a look at this also: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1372695